# Install Gnome Software Center

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome

I installed Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 and then upgraded the Gnome version to 3.10. But, all new apps in 3.10 such as Gnome Software Center, Maps, Weather etc are not included. So now, I wonder how to get and install these apps, especially Gnome Software Center?

Comment: Download from [here](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/System/Software-Distribution/GNOME-Software-102470.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

You said you have installed Gnome 3.10, that means you probably have already added Gnome 3 and Gnome 3 next ppas.

I don't think packages for all the new apps that you have mentioned are available in the gnome ppas, so far I have seen only the weather app. The package name is gnome-weather, and is available via the Gnome 3 staging ppa.

Gnome music is available via ricotz/testing.

I guess you will need to build the sources if you really want to try the others.

Some other pretty apps are Gnome notes and clocks, I am not sure whether they come installed with Ubuntu Gnome. The notes application package is named bijiben, but it is at version 3.8, gnome-clocks is at 3.10 and uses CSD.

Update: Gnome maps is now added to staging ppa.

Comment: Does those apps require Gnome 3.10? I went back to Gnome 3.8 (because some extensions I like want 3.8) and then tried to install gnome-clocks, bijiben (notes), gnome-photos and gnome-weather through ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3. The first two worked, but when I try to install the last two, apt-get says that the package can no be found. According to this link (https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3) those packages should be available through the ppa.

Comment: See maybe this: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/09/how-to-install-gnome-310-in-ubuntu-1310.html -- it wont give you everything, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. If you install the `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` metapackage from USC or APT, it might add some of the components. It will **NOT** add them all. Gnome Software is not included, because it does not support APT (at least to my knowledge), and even if it did, it would be redundant because of USC.

The sources should be available at:

https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Maps

https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Weather

For other apps, there is a list at https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps

Feel free to get back to me if you need any more help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could type in the terminal:

sudo apt-get install software-center

and it might work fine this way.